# Accessing all the data contained in an h5 file with python

Tags: python, h5py

After I load an h5 files and then check the keys, is there any other data that can be stored in the h5 that I might be missing? For example:

```
import h5py
a = '/path/to/file.h5'
a_h5 = h5py.File(a)
a_h5.keys()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [h5py documentation](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/attr.html), it looks like you can also do:

```
a_h5.values()
a_h5.items()
```

I don't know much about this format, but this looks like additional information you can extract.

Comment: There is not really much additional information that you couldn't get from the keys. It's just that you get the items too at the same time.